# Scala Weird Class/Object initalization in Traits

Tags: scala

I can't find an answer why this code throws an exception for `assertProperChildren(Zoo2)`, but only if `Zoo2.Tiger` is accessed before making the assert. If you comment that access line, all asserts work. Doesn't make sense to me. Is this a known Scala bug?

```
trait Domain {
  abstract class ChildDomain
  def children: Seq[ChildDomain]
}

// V1
abstract class Zoo1 extends Domain {
  object Tiger extends ChildDomain
  val children = Seq(Tiger)
}
object Zoo1 extends Zoo1

// V2
object Zoo2 extends Domain {
  object Tiger extends ChildDomain
  val children = Seq(Tiger)
}

// V3
object Zoo3 extends Domain {
  object Tiger extends ChildDomain
  lazy val children = Seq(Tiger)
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def assertProperChildren(domain: Domain) = {
      assert(!domain.children.contains(null))
    }
    Zoo1.Tiger
    // Will NOT crash here, even if we touch Zoo1.Tiger before Zoo1
    assertProperChildren(Zoo1)
    Zoo2.Tiger
    // Will crash here, but only if we touch Zoo2.Tiger before Zoo2
    assertProperChildren(Zoo2)
    // So if we want a scala object directly inheriting from a Domain
    // we need lazy children:
    Zoo3.Tiger
    assertProperChildren(Zoo3)
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this one: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html

Comment: This code should not crash. It might throw an exception, but – barring any compiler or runtime bugs – it should be pretty much impossible to crash a Scala program.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You are right, clarified my question

Comment: @ShankarShastri cheers, that explains it

Comment: @longliveenduro, I've posted the answer, please mark the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala follows initialization order, it's explained in the below link as FAQs.
 https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html

You can use `-Xcheckinit` as part of scalac flag. To validate the same.